# Error when trying to assigning interface

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
class Klass {
  baseAttr: string;
}

class ChildKlass extends Klass {
  childAttr: string;
}

interface T1<T extends Klass = Klass> {
  readonly display: ReadonlyArray<keyof T>;
}

class T1Klass implements T1<ChildKlass> {
  readonly display: ReadonlyArray<keyof ChildKlass> = ['childAttr'];
}
```

Everything works fine above...

---

The problem comes when I try to create a "dictionary" where the value should be:

`t1` - "an instance of class that implements T1";
`klass` - "an instance of class that extends Klass"

```
interface ConstructableT1 {
  new(): T1;
}

interface T1KlassDictionary {
  [key: string]: {
    // Since I can't just say t1 is typeof T1, I created the ConstructableT1 interface
    t1?: ConstructableT1,
    klass?: typeof Klass
  };
}
```

When I try to instantiate an `object`:

```
const dictionary: T1KlassDictionary = {
  test: {
    t1: T1Klass,
    klass: ChildKlass
  }
};
```

... it gives me the following error:

> Type 'typeof T1Klass' is not assignable to type 'ConstructableT1'.

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20T1%3CT%20extends%20Klass%20%3D%20Klass%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20display%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Ckeyof%20T%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ConstructableT1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new()%3A%20T1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20T1Klass%20implements%20T1%3CChildKlass%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20display%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Ckeyof%20ChildKlass%3E%20%3D%20%5B'id'%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Klass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20attr%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ChildKlass%20extends%20Klass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20T1KlassDictionary%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t1%3F%3A%20ConstructableT1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20klass%3F%3A%20typeof%20Klass%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20dictionary%3A%20T1KlassDictionary%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t1%3A%20T1Klass%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20klass%3A%20ChildKlass%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type 'typeof T1Klass' is not assignable to type 'ConstructableT1'.

TypeScript compiler shortens error messages sometimes. In this case, it does not tell why `typeof T1Klass` is not assignable to `ConstructableT1`.

To see why, let's try to assign one to another:

```
let a: typeof T1Klass;
let b: ConstructableT1 = a;
```

Now we get

```
Type 'typeof T1Klass' is not assignable to type 'ConstructableT1'.
  Type 'T1Klass' is not assignable to type 'T1<Klass>'.
    Types of property 'display' are incompatible.
      Type 'ReadonlyArray<"id" | "attr">' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray<"attr">'.
        Type '"id" | "attr"' is not assignable to type '"attr"'.
          Type '"id"' is not assignable to type '"attr"'.
```

Which seems reasonable - one possible key value - "id" - is not assignable to a value of literal type "attr".

One possible solution is to make `interface ConstructableT1` generic, so the compiler will know the actual type of `t1` and will not use default for generic parameter (`T1Klass`) which is incompatible:

```
interface T1<T extends Klass = Klass> {
    readonly display: ReadonlyArray<keyof T>;
}

interface ConstructableT1<T extends Klass = Klass> {
    new(): T1<T>;
}



class T1Klass implements T1<ChildKlass> {
    readonly display: ReadonlyArray<keyof ChildKlass> = ['id'];
}


class Klass {
    attr: string;
}

class ChildKlass extends Klass {
    id: string;
}

interface T1KlassDictionary {
    [key: string]: {
        t1?: ConstructableT1<ChildKlass>,
        klass?: typeof Klass
    };
}

const dictionary: T1KlassDictionary = {
    test: {
        t1: T1Klass,
        klass: ChildKlass
    }
};
```

**UPDATE** the question was clarified:

> The problem comes when I try to create a "dictionary" where the value
>   should be:
>
> t1 - "an instance of class that implements T1"; klass - "an instance
>   of class that extends Klass"

Then I'd say you have wrong types for `t1` and `klass`. You declared them as constructors - that is, `dictionary.t1` can be used for creating instances like this

```
const inst = new dictionary.test.t1();
```

the playground says that the type of `inst` created this way is `const inst: T1<ChildKlass>`.

If the dictionary should contain instances, it should be declared like this

```
interface T1KlassDictionary {
    [key: string]: {
        t1?: T1<ChildKlass>,
        klass?: Klass
    };
}
```

and initialized with instances created with `new()`

```
const dictionary: T1KlassDictionary = {
    test: {
        t1: new T1Klass(),
        klass: new ChildKlass()
    }
};
```

then you can access instance properties:

```
const attr = dictionary.test.klass.attr; 
// but no id because declared type of `klass`
//  is `Klass` which does not have `id`

const attr = dictionary.test.t1.display;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation... however I want to be able to access the properties of those classes, ex: `dictionary.test.t1.display` or `dictionary.test.klass.id` and I have no idea how to do this. In fact, I forgot to mention this in OP (added right now). Can you help me anyway?